# Determine all $a$ so that $\langle .,.\rangle^{'}$ defines an inner product and find for these values an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, orthonormal

Let $V$ be a vector space and $W$  an inner product space with an inner product $\langle.,.\rangle$.

Let $T : V \rightarrow W$ be a linear image. Define $\langle u,v\rangle^{'} = \langle T(u),T(v)\rangle$ with $u,v \in V$

I already proved that $\langle .,.\rangle^{'}$ defines a inner product on $V$ if and only is T is one-to-one.
But the second question about this confuses me.

b) Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Say that $V=W=\mathbb{R^2}$ and $T: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}: X \longmapsto AX$ with $$A = \begin{bmatrix}3&3a\\\ 0& a\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Let $\langle .,.\rangle$ be the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Determine all $a$ so that $\langle .,.\rangle^{'}$ defines an inner product on $\mathbb{R^2}$ and find for these values an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the inner product $\langle .,.\rangle^{'}$.

I don't see how to handle this question, but I think for the second part I just need to use Gram Schmidt?

Comment: I don't see any question in b).

Comment: The question was mistakenly deleted, I edited it

Comment: So, based on your previous work, you just have to decide, for which values of $a$ is the map $x\mapsto Ax$ one-one, right?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: Then all you need to do is find all $a$ such that the kernel is trivial, that is, such that, if $Ax=0$, then $x=0$.

Comment: Maybe by computing its determinant.

Comment: @GerryMyerson so if it's injective the dimension of the kernel is $0$ so for example $a$  can't be $0$ otherwise we have a row of zero's?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe why would that be helpful? You get $det(A) = 0$ but wat can you do with that info?

Comment: You get $\det(A)=3a=0\iff a=0$.  In that case $A$ isn't bijective.

Comment: Oh yes I calculated the determinant wrong. That's the only case right? Then I just use Gram Schmidt for the vectors $v_1 = (3,0)$ and $v_2 = (3a,a)$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}$ without $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
\begin{align}
\textrm{$\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle'$ is an inner product in $\mathbb R^2$} 
& \ \Leftrightarrow \ \textrm{$T$ is injective} \\
& \ \Leftrightarrow \ \textrm{the kernel of $T$ is trivial} \\
& \ \Leftrightarrow \ \textrm{if $T(X)=0$ then $X=0$} \\
& \ \Leftrightarrow \ \textrm{if $\begin{bmatrix}3&3a\\0&a\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ then $\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$} \\
& \ \Leftrightarrow \ \textrm{if $x_1 \begin{bmatrix}3\\0\end{bmatrix} + x_2 \begin{bmatrix}3a\\a\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ then $x_1=0$ and $x_2=0$}
\end{align}
so, it suffices to find all the values of $a$ for which the vectors $$\textrm{$\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}3a\\a\end{bmatrix}$}$$ are linearly independent. You can use your favorite method for this! And for the second part, yes, you can apply the Gram-Schmidt process to the standard unit vectors
$$\textrm{$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$}$$ with the new inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle'$.